# What is the canonical way to set fixed parameters and retrieve them after a study is complete?

Tags: python, optuna

Optuna allows users to search a parameter space using the `suggest_` API. This is easy and clever enough.

However, there are some parameters I would like to remain fixed. For example, with Scikit-Learn's DBSCAN implementation:

Search using `suggest_` API:

- `eps`
- `min_samples`

Keep fixed:

- `metric`
- `n_jobs`

One might suggest I hard-code `metric` and `n_jobs` in my objective function, like so:

```py
def objective(trial: Trial) -> float:
    eps: float = trial.suggest_float(
        name='eps',
        low=self.eps_minimum,
        high=self.eps_maximum,
    )
    min_samples: int = trial.suggest_int(
        name='min_samples',
        low=self.min_samples_minimum,
        high=self.min_samples_maximum,
    )
    clustering = DBSCAN(
        eps=eps,
        min_samples=min_samples,
        metric='cosine',         # <-- hard-coded
        n_jobs=16,               # <-- hard-coded
    ).fit_predict(X=vectors)     # <-- `vectors` is in scope but not shown
    return adjusted_rand_score(
        labels_true=labels,      # <-- `labels` is in scope but not shown
        labels_pred=clustering,
    )
```

However, **I also would like to be able to retrieve these parameters' arguments from the Optuna Study at a later point**. To my knowledge, Optuna offers no `study.fixed_params` attribute.

To expose these fixed parameters, I have resorted to setting them via the `suggest_` API, and providing only one possible option for the search space. I found that setting `trial.params['custom'] = 42` within the objective function doesn't work.

I am unhappy with this solution because the `study.best_params`' output implies (to me, at least) that these values were found during the hyperparameter search.

**Question:** Is this the canonical way of achieving my goal? Or is there another approach?

I am new to Optuna, so please excuse my naïveté.

---

```py
from typing import *
from os import sched_getaffinity
from dataclasses import dataclass
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score

import optuna
from optuna.study.study import Study
from optuna.trial._trial import Trial


@dataclass
class Objective:
    eps_minimum: float
    eps_maximum: float
    min_samples_minimum: int
    min_samples_maximum: int
    dbscan_metric: Sequence[str, ...] = ('cosine',)
    n_jobs: int = len(sched_getaffinity(1)) - 1 or 1

    def __call__(self, trial: Trial) -> float:
        eps: float = trial.suggest_float(
            name='eps',
            low=self.eps_minimum,
            high=self.eps_maximum,
        )
        min_samples: int = trial.suggest_int(
            name='min_samples',
            low=self.min_samples_minimum,
            high=self.min_samples_maximum,
        )
        dbscan_metric: str = trial.suggest_categorical(
            name='metric',
            choices=self.dbscan_metric,
        )
        n_jobs: int = trial.suggest_int(
            name='n_jobs',
            low=self.n_jobs,
            high=self.n_jobs,
        )
        clustering = DBSCAN(
            eps=eps,
            min_samples=min_samples,
            metric=dbscan_metric,
            n_jobs=n_jobs,
        ).fit_predict(X=vectors)
        return adjusted_rand_score(
            labels_true=labels,
            labels_pred=clustering,
        )

objective_dbscan: ObjectiveDBSCAN = ObjectiveDBSCAN(...)
study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize')
study.optimize(objective_dbscan, n_trials=...)

...

>>> study.best_params
# this returns a dictionary with eps, min_samples, metric, and n_jobs
```

Optuna Version: 2.9.1

Comment: If it is only for tracking parameters, you may use MLflow on top of optuna. MLflow can store hyperparameters, metrics, etc in DB. There is some doc for using optuna with mlflow [there](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.integration.MLflowCallback.html) BTW, if, like me, you wanted to fix the parameters of one trialI for example for debugging, there is `optuna.trial.FixedTrial` that may help (see more [here](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.trial.FixedTrial.html)).

Answer (score 4):

The standard is to use [set_user_attr](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.trial.Trial.html#optuna.trial.Trial.set_user_attr)

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

import optuna

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)


def objective(trial):
    trial.set_user_attr("BATCHSIZE", 128)
    momentum = trial.suggest_float("momentum", 0, 1.0)
    clf = MLPClassifier(
        hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 50),
        batch_size=trial.user_attrs["BATCHSIZE"],
        momentum=momentum,
        solver="sgd",
        random_state=0,
    )
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    return clf.score(X_valid, y_valid)
```

So the search space will be accessed by:

```
trial_with_highest_ob = max(study.best_trials, key=lambda t: t.values[0]) 
print(trial_with_highest_ob.params)
```

and the constant values by `optuna.trial.Trial.user_attrs()`:

```
study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize")
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=3)
assert "BATCHSIZE" in study.best_trial.user_attrs.keys()
assert study.best_trial.user_attrs["BATCHSIZE"] == 128
```

which isn't so practical.

If you want to circumvent this and get all the parameters packed under the same method you can add constant suggestions under you search space:

```py
delta_t = trial.suggest_int("delta_t", 1, 5, step=1)
asso_func = trial.suggest_categorical("asso_func", ['iou'])  # constant
inertia = trial.suggest_categorical("inertia", [0.1])  # constant
use_byte = trial.suggest_categorical("use_byte", [True, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use user attribute.

In the objective().

```
njobs = 16
trial.set_user_attr("n_jobs", njobs)
```

Then retrieve it with.

```
njobs = study.best_trial.user_attrs['n_jobs']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that might be useful here is the [Partial Fixed Sampler](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.samplers.PartialFixedSampler.html#optuna.samplers.PartialFixedSampler).

In the example they give, one parameter is initially tuned and then fixed after a set number of trials. In your case, you could fix multiple parameters from the start instead.

Be warned that this is currently marked as an experimental feature.

A MWE might look something like this:

```
import optuna


class Objective:
    fixed_params = {
        'y': -1,
    }

    def __call__(self, trial):
        x = trial.suggest_float("x", -1, 1)
        # This is overridden by the fixed parameter.
        y = trial.suggest_int("y", -1, 1)
        return x ** 2 + y


objective = Objective()
study = optuna.create_study()
partial_sampler = optuna.samplers.PartialFixedSampler(objective.fixed_params, study.sampler)
study.sampler = partial_sampler
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=10)
```

Here, y is a fixed parameter, but as it is still defined in `trial.suggest_int(...)`, it still appears in the set of best parameters (i.e., the parameter list will contain `x` and `y`). If you would like it to not appear in the list of best parameters, simply remove that line and replace it with `y = self.fixed_params['y']`. Now the parameter list will only contain `x`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30546241)

Comment: Thank you for the review comments. I have added a MWE example now that should aid with clarity.